# Assign a group number to a set of transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, grouping, rank, row-number

Not sure the title is appropriate but couldn't think how else to phrase it.  Here's the question.

I am trying to determine if a client used all of their benefits during a membership period.  Here is what I have so far.

```
Select
       HospitalMasterID
      ,PatientID
      ,TxnCode
      ,TxnDate
      ,PlanDate
From Treatments
where PN = 1
Order By PatientID, TxnDate
```

Now what I need to do is assign a grouping based on the PlanDate.  It is likely that a patient has renewed the plan.  So from March 2012 - March 2013 they have used 5 separate benefits. Then repurchased the plan in March of 2013 so it starts again.  I want to know how many and what benefits they are not using from 2012. In order to do this I need to find a way to categorize the groupings- I can't just use year as the plan can be purchased any time and it is active for a full year from purchase.

This has to be done for many patients at once-
Using SQL 2008R2

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select
       HospitalMasterID
      ,PatientID
      ,TxnCode
      ,TxnDate
      ,PlanDate
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID, PlanDate ORDER BY TxnDate) AS GroupNumber
From Treatments
where PN = 1
Order By PatientID, TxnDate
```

or probably

```
SELECT PatientID, PlanDate, Max(GroupNumber) as BenefitCount
FROM (
  Select
       HospitalMasterID
      ,PatientID
      ,TxnCode
      ,TxnDate
      ,PlanDate
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID, PlanDate ORDER BY TxnDate) AS GroupNumber
  From Treatments
  where PN = 1
)
GROUP BY PatientID, PlanDate
```

Comment: Hogan- thanks but that just gave me row numbers within a group.  I was looking for some way to number the groups.  So all Txns with PlanDate of 2012-02-10 would be group 1 and all txns with plandate 2013-03-04 would be group 2 and all txns with plandate 2014-03-05 would be group 3.  I think I was looking for Dense_Rank or something like that but could not fully remember.

Comment: @SASUSMC - That would be `PARTITION BY CAST(PathientID as VARCHAR(max))+CAST(PlanDate AS VARCHAR(max)` which would be kinda slow

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but I think I will use a combination of PatientID, PlanDate to do this.

IN which case the original query works.